# How to solve the problem of unable to prompt .click() in a call function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to prompt `.click()` on a certain button on my website after calling the function named `saveIt()`.

However, I cannot prompt the `.click()` after calling the `saveIt()` function.

```
function saveIt() {
    $('button[onclick="saveToCloud(this);"]')[0].click();
}
setInterval(saveIt, 1000);
```

I have tried the code below and it prompt `.click()` successfully, but not with the coding shown above.

```
var saveIt=setInterval(function() {
    $('button[onclick="saveToCloud(this);"]')[0].click();
}, 500);
```

Comment: I don't know your detail code, but as per your code statements- you can use:
 $('button[onclick="saveToCloud(this);"]')[0].trigger("click");

Comment: This seems a bad design for me (there's very few information in your question). Instead of triggering the click, shouldn't both click handler and saveit function call the same function, which contains the logic? Think responsibility ... business code shouldn't be located in a UI handler. But as I said, you didn't described what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns *intervalID* which you can used to clear the interval using `clearInterval(intervalID)` [More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). So initiating a variable from `setInterval` will not create a function.

Here is an example creating a function `saveIt` which starts the `setInterval`.

```js
var saveIt= function(){
    // we defined a function that runs setInterval
    setInterval(function() {
       $('button[onclick="saveToCloud(this);"]')[0].click();
    }, 500);
}
```

You can also define it as normal function

```js
function saveIt(){
    // we defined a function that runs setInterval
    setInterval(function() {
       $('button[onclick="saveToCloud(this);"]')[0].click();
    }, 500);
}


// later call saveIt()
saveIt();
```

Comment: Your code writing style is better than the old code writing that I found on another forum. Thank you for your bits of help and comments. It helped me to solve the problem.